# how can I receive ACTION_SCREEN_ON at my widget?

Tags: android

I know that there is way to receive broadcast intents ACTION_SCREEN_ON at activity or service. But my widget doesn't have any activity or service. Only widget. Is is possible to receive ACTION_SCREEN_ON at my widget? Then how?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, sorry.

If you only want to update the app widget when the screen is on, use `AlarmManager` with an `ELAPSED_REALTIME` (not `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`) alarm.