# Android - update widget over service with data from network. Best approach?

Tags: android, networking, service, widget

I have a question regarding Android widgets and especially Android services. Here is what I want to do: On the phone the user should be able to add my widget to his homescreen. The widget gets its data from network.
After reading some tutrials about this, I found out that the best approach would be to create a service that gets the data from network (TCP sockets) and then updates the widget constantly. That is done with ScheduledExecutorService which executes a Runnable in a certain interval. 
The Runnable will connect to a server, get the data and should update the widget).

My problem is now, that the widget don't need to be updated when the screen is off and so the service should not run because of battery drain. My question is: How to do it the best way?

**I found 2 approaches which would more or less do what I want:**

1. When the first instance of the widget is added to homescreen, it will register a Broadcast Receiver that receives the ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF intent action from Android OS.
   If ACTION_SCREEN_ON is fired, it will start the updater service, otherwise it will stop it. But I'm really unsure if that's a good approach because of the broadcast receiver lifetime.
2. In the updater service's Runnable, which is executed periodically by the ScheduledExecutorService and actually does the network stuff, I check via PowerManager.isScreenOn(), if the screen is on. If yes, I execute the network code, otherwise not. But what is when the device is in standby? Is this code executed then? What about battery drain here?

Is there maybe a "best practice" approach for what I want to do? I've read alot about the AlarmManager and that it is a very powerful tool. Can you schedule tasks with this in the way, that they are only executed when the display is on?

Thanks for your help.

Best Regards
NiThDi

Comment: Did you give any thought about [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)? This way you would not need to poll for data (even if only for when device is awake) and you would get new data only when it changed. Plus you would get a benefit of displaying the latest piece of it when user wakes his device, without any initial delay.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the fast answer. I don't think that Google Cloud Messaging can do what I want. The point is (to get clear), that the server mentioned above is not ONE server for all users. It is a server application running in their computers. In fact, this app is a remote control which connects to the server on a computer in LAN over TCP/IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first solution (widget handling screen ON and OFF broadcasts) to the problem is the way to go. Start a new [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) for a background communication to your application server. Once it finished, send your custom "Completed" broadcast with results and then handle it in your widget.

As an additional benefit it would allow multiple instances of your widget to work from one "source" and would not consume any resources in case user did not add any widgets.

**UPDATE** As it is impossible to use screen ON/OFF broadcasts with a widget, I would probably use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4545610/181714) (AlarmManager with an `ELAPSED_REALTIME` (not `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`) alarm) to schedule an (intent) service run. This way your service will not be scheduled when screen is off, but will run periodically when it is on. And if the delay between screen ON and OFF is more than the period it will run immediately on screen coming back ON.

As for your question about broadcast receivers lifetime, as said before, use IntentService for a long running task and then broadcast your results back from it. When you starting a service that call does not block so broadcast receiver will finish in a timely matter.

**UPDATE 2** According to [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/Airlo3g5luw/OcLEUW2aq6UJ) screen OFF does not mean device is sleeping. You already have a solution to this issue by using PowerManager.isScreenOn().

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what about the broadcast receiver lifecycle? I know that a widget is a broadcast receiver as well, but it seems that a class extending AppWidgetProvider can't receive the ACTION_SCREEN_ON/OFF actions. And unfortunately if I register a new broadcast receiver (so a class extinding BroadcastReceiver) I can't be sure about the lifetime. I assume it is correct that Android can kill any BroadcastREceiver if it needs memory?!

Comment: I was not paying attention to screen ON/OFF thing. You are right, it is not possible to use it with a widget. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The ELAPSED_REALTIME approach could work I think, but strangly it is not for a small test app I created. 
Basically the test app is a widget and a IntentService. The widget only shows the current time, while the Intent Service gets the current time and sends a broadcast which the widget consumes in the onReceive() method and updates itself. The widget is of course a registered receiver for the custom broadcast action.
In the onEnabled() method in the widget, I initialize the alarm for AlarmManager. Now some code:

**Widget onEnabled():**

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context c) {
    super.onEnabled(c);

    Intent intent = new Intent(c.getApplicationContext(), SimpleIntentService.class);

    PendingIntent intentExecuted = PendingIntent.getService(c.getApplicationContext(), 45451894, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) c.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 0, 3000, intentExecuted);
}
```

**Widget onReceive():**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_RESP)) {
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), Widget.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        for (int appWidgetId : allWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

            String s = "";

            if (intent.hasExtra("msg")) s = intent.getStringExtra("msg");

            // Set the text
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, s);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(allWidgetIds, remoteViews);
        }
    }
}
```

**SimpleIntentService onHandleIntent():**

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.w("TestService", "SimpleIntentService onHandleIntent called.");
    String msg = new Date().toGMTString();

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction(Widget.ACTION_RESP);
    broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
```

So, I have tested this on my Nexus 4 running Android 4.2.1 and on an emulator with Android 4.0.4. In both cases the SimpleIntentService gets created and onHandleIntent() gets called every 3 seconds, even when I manually turn the display off.
I have absolutely no idea why the AlarmManager still schedules the alarm, do you have?!

Thank you!

Comment: According to [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/Airlo3g5luw/OcLEUW2aq6UJ) screen off does not mean device is sleeping. You already have a solution to this issue by using  `PowerManager.isScreenOn()`.